# Vocal Mixing Help

Tags: voice, mixing, daw, cubase

I'm doing a cover of a song, and I'm trying to replicate the way the vocals in the original song were mixed. This is the original song:

I've been working on this simple task for days with no success. Some things I have tried include:

- Harmonizer VSTs
- Shifting two duplicate vocal tracks down a couple cents and up a
  couple cents on either side of the main vocal track
- Adding a quieter, second vocal track sung an octave higher
- A "tonebooster" VST

None of these seemed to give me the same sound as the original. I assume I must just be missing something since I have limited experience using DAWs. (I use Cubase elements).

Do any of you have some insight on how the original artist got the vocals to sound like they do in the original song? I'd love to hear any ideas you may have.

If it helps any, here's my most successful mix, which unfortunately is not so great:

Thanks!

Comment: I can't help you with the mixing but I like your cover better than the original.  Far more intelligible.  Without the lyrics on screen I would not even know what language the singer in the video was singing.  You don't always have to have a perfect match of the original to make a great cover.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are hearing is a vocoder. See if Cubase has a vocoder plug in. That should do the trick.

Your cover sounds great by the way.